# FileManager and urlsForDirectory Error in Swift 3 Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I just went to Xcode 8 beta 4 from beta 3 but for what ever reason I am getting this error that has worked with no errors or issued until beta 4. here is the error" `Value of type 'FileManager' has no member 'urlsForDirectory'` "

my code:

```
 func setupRecorder(){

        let audioSession:AVAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

        //ask for permission
        if (audioSession.responds(to: #selector(AVAudioSession.requestRecordPermission(_:)))) {
            AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission({(granted: Bool)-> Void in
                if granted {
                    print("Permission Granted\n")

                    //set category and activate recorder session
                    do {
                        //----
                        let fileManager = FileManager.default
                        let urls = fileManager.urlsForDirectory(.documentDirectory, inDomains: .userDomainMask)
                        //----
                        let documentDirectory = urls[0] as URL
                        let soundURL = try! documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("sound.m4a")

                        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)

                        try self.soundRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(url: soundURL, settings: self.recordSettings)

                       let micInput = try AVAudioRecorder(url
                        : soundURL, settings: self.recordSettings)


                        self.soundRecorder.prepareToRecord()
                        self.soundRecorder.updateMeters()



                    } catch {

                        print("Error Recording");

                    }

                }
            })
        }

    }
```

BUT the only part is this line:

```
                let urls = fileManager.urlsForDirectory(.documentDirectory, inDomains: .userDomainMask)
```

" `'Value of type 'FileManager' has no member 'urlsForDirectory'`"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to change it to `urls(for:)` as follow:

```
let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
```

Comment: Or func contentsOfDirectory(at url: URL, includingPropertiesForKeys keys: [URLResourceKey]?, options mask: FileManager.DirectoryEnumerationOptions = []) throws -> [URL]