# Value of type 'FileManager' has no member 'urlsForDirectory' - AppDelegate Swift 3 Error

Tags: core-data, appdelegate, swift3, xcode8

Since I recently updated to XCode 8 Beta 5 I have been trying to solve this error in my appDelegate Core Data Stack.

In these lines of code I get the following error:

```
// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: URL = {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "fitness.paceapp.Pace" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
    let urls = FileManager.default.urlsForDirectory(.documentDirectory, inDomains: .userDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1]
}()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = Bundle.main.urlForResource("Dominos", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
}()
```

[image]

Any Ideas on what I could be missing. I am quite lost and there are not many answers out there. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you had a look at the new [`FileManager` API reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsfilemanager)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FileManager and urlsForDirectory Error in Swift 3 Xcode Beta 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38754426/filemanager-and-urlsfordirectory-error-in-swift-3-xcode-beta-4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go,

```
lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: URL = {
        // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "fitness.paceapp.Pace" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
        let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask)
        return urls[urls.count-1]
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
        // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
        let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Dominos", withExtension: "momd")!
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
    }()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is:

```
let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
return urls.last!
```

Or

```
return try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
```